# Create a 2 dimension Quickreport

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, quickreports

I think im asking for the right type of report from Quickreport.

What we have is a simple table,

```
gauge,site,value
```

Gauge and site are the keyfields, (there could be anynumber of Gauge-Site Pairs)
normally there is only at most, about 10 sites.

and we are looking to get a reports that looks like this

```
       site1   site2   site3
gauge1   34      4      45
gauge2   45      6       5
gauge4   34      4      45
```

Dose anyone know

- What type this type of report is normally called, (so google can be more help)
- Is is possible to created this type of report using QuickReport
   if so, any ideas how?
   if not, any ideas on what could be used insted?

Delphi7
QuickReports 3.5
NexusDB (dont think that matters too much)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a cross tabulation. Google for "crosstab", "crosstab report", "crosstab object".

Comment: http://64.233.169.132/search?q=cache:pcE7ec8zXP8J:www.qusoft.com/stanlegacy.html+quickreport+crosstab+how+to&hl=en&ct=clnk&cd=1&gl=us

for example.

-Al.

Comment: @ChristopherChase link is no longer available, could you find the correct one please?

Comment: @bluish Sorry i never used the link, the cross tabulation keyword is what i searched for

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a memtable (for example with memoryData of JVCL suite (free)) then print a normal report.